# How to take a specif commit and move it to another branch and keep the changes

Tags: git, github

I added a very large file and had to delete it from the commit.
When I did that something happened and it mixed up the commits, brought old commits to my branch. Now i had 5 months commits

So I need to take the commits I made on that branch (3 commits) and take it to a new branch.

[image]
(In the image we have dozens of commits, and the last 3, which are mine that I want to keep)

Is there any way I can do this without bringing these old commits? like a git stash?

obs: repo in github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `git cherry-pick` might be a good option if you know which commits you want on the new branch:

```
git checkout -b my-new-branch <sha of first commit you want>
git cherry-pick <sha of next commit on the new branch>
git cherry-pick <sha of next commit...>
```

Comment: Man, you are a life saver, really thanks!!!!
Every thread about this always talk about git revert or gir reset.
This work really fine, easy and accurate.